# Rails redirect with proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, nginx, devise, proxy

I configured grunt-connect-proxy (based on http-node-proxy actually) to proxy my requests on `localhost:3000` to my backend hosted `myserver.com`.

The backend app is running on Nginx (+ nginx passenger module) + passenger. There is no reverse proxy here.

The nginx configuration is like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root  /home/deployer/app/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/app.access.log;

    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html;
        break;
    }

   location ~* ^/assets/  {
      try_files $uri 404;
   }

    location ~* ^.+.(css|js|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /nginx_status {
       stub_status on;
       access_log   off;
       allow 127.0.0.1;
       deny all;
    }
}
```

It's actually like the one described here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu

The first request is OK: when I type `localhost:3000`, I am actually on myserver.com.
HTTP code = 200.

When I try to go to a protected page (with Devise), let's say `http://localhost:3000/admin/articles`, I get a HTTP code = 302 but I am redirected to `myserver.com`.

This means: I can log on `myserver.com` but not can't be logged on `localhost:3000`.

How can I tell Rails or Devise to consider the proxied address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue was here: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb#L88

I had to send the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST` header with value = `localhost:3000`.
Then, it grunt proxy, you would have something like:

```
        {
          context: ['/'],
          host: 'myserver.com',
          port: 80,
          https: false,
          changeOrigin: true,
          xforward: true,
          headers: {
            'x-forwarded-host': 'localhost:3000'
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really supply any data of your configuration, but I think your problem is that you didn't set the `proxy_redirect`

Add this line in the same block that contains the `proxy_pass`

```
proxy_redirect default;
```